# MongoDB Cloud Manager Vs Mongodb Atlas

Tags: mongodb

can anyone please give me a high level difference between MongoDB Cloud Manager and Mongodb Atlas. My main aim is to monitor mongodb instances in AWS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Cloud Manager is used when you want to manage your own infrastructure (you spin up the nodes where MongoDB runs) but still have the benefits of automated backups and monitoring.

Atlas goes one step further by automating everything for you including provisioning the infrastructure. It's a true database as a service fully managed by MongoDB. They hide the complexity of managing servers so all you have to worry about it using MongoDB. It's interesting to note they use AWS (with plans to support Azure and Google) to spin up nodes, perform monitoring, and backups.

Comment: But Cloud Manager is offers also a db hosting, am I right?

Comment: Cloud Manager provides the tooling to host MongoDB not the actual hardware. As said on their site: "A hosted platform for managing MongoDB on the infrastructure of your choice."

Answer (score 2):

The Major difference between Atlas and Cloud manager is that :

- Cloud manager is used for monitoring your database deployment and providing the automated back ups in the self hosted environment.

While MongoDB Atlas is used when your deployments are hosted on the MongoDB Servers. So each and ever task is managed by the MongoDB staff. This is basically the database as a service. In case you encounter any issue all you need to open a case with the mongodb and they will help in the investigations of the issue occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an up-to-date answer to this question which explains differences between Atlas, Cloud Manager and also the Ops-Manager:

**MongoDB Atlas** handles all the complexity of deploying, managing, and healing your deployments on the cloud service provider of your choice (AWS, Azure, and GCP). Atlas pricing details are here 4.

**Cloud Manager** is a platform for managing MongoDB on the infrastructure of your choice. Cloud Manager pricing details are here 7.

**Ops Manager** automate, monitor, and back up your MongoDB infrastructure.

Here is the original article and additional resources in the MongoDB community forum: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/cloud-manager-vs-ops-manager-vs-atlas/42624